# List all downstreams project for a project in jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins

This must be a simple rookie mistake but

```
    def hi = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
   hi.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each {project ->
   println(project.displayName)
   def di = project.getDownstreamProjects

   println(di.name)

}
```

just returns

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: getDownstreamProjects for class: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject
```

but [the doc](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/FreeStyleProject.html) say the method exist on the AbstractProject
What do I do wrong?

Comment: For a jenkins noob, how would I Run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `()` after `getDownstreamProjects`. It's a method not a property ;-)

Comment: gaahh, m(, to much haskell lately

Comment: I feel with you, I've been doing some Scala lately and keep forgetting brackets left and right in Java since then ;-)